# How to run web application in virtual machine using tomcat in the real machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, java, eclipse

I´m `Java` developer and I´m want to test the system in different browser.

My virtual machine is `Virtual Box` and I´m using `Windows Xp` with Internet Explorer 6, so I want to access `Tomcat` application in the `VM`. But I put in my `Windows 8.1` rule in firewall to accept connection in port 8080.

I run `Tomcat` with `Eclipse`.

But still not opening.

So what should I do?

Comment: Can you add some clarification please, is your real machine windows 8.1 or xp?  also have you tried pinging the virtual machine to test the network connection between the host and VM?

Comment: Real machine is 8.1. Ping worked

Comment: How is the guest VM's network card configured? Specifically, what is it attached to? Is attached to "NAT"?

Comment: It's configured NAT

Comment: The host can't access the guest through a VM adapter configured as NAT. But beyond that, I don't understand your question well enough to give any advice. In the title you say that tomcat is in the "real machine", but in the question you say it's in the VM? Could you do a better job of explaining what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I got! I changed my network to bridge mode, and worked!